# VBA userform formula

Tags: vba, excel, formulas

Good afternoon,

I have built a userform and the userform populates the data on to the data table using offsets etc. The problem I have is one of the formulas is looking up the description of the product from a list on a separate tab, but it is deleting the zeroes contained within the product code rendering the formula useless for example:

The formula

```
ActiveCell.Offset(x, 17) = "=If(LEFT(" & ActiveCell.Offset(x, 16) & ",1)=""Z"",VLOOKUP(" & ActiveCell.Offset(x, 16) & ",Masterdata!A:B,2,0),VLOOKUP(TEXT(" & ActiveCell.Offset(x, 16) & ",0),Masterdata!A:B,2,0))"
```

Product code it is looking up is Z6532018-11-002-17

After the VBA has run, the formula in the cell looks like this:

```
=IF(LEFT(Z6532018-11-2-17,1)="Z",VLOOKUP(Z6532018-11-2-17,Masterdata!A:B,2,0),VLOOKUP(TEXT(Z6532018-11-2-17,0),Masterdata!A:B,2,0))
```

It has automatcially deleted the 00 from 002-17 within the product code.

Any ideas on how to stop this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using the cell address instead of putting the reference:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(x, 16).Address(0,0)
```

If you do not wnt that  then you will need to add `"` around the lookup.

```
""" & ActiveCell.Offset(x, 16) & """
```

So it returns: `"Z6532018-11-002-17"` not just the text.  The text needs to have a `"` on either end in the finished formula.

Comment: Or, write explicit code and do `""" & ActiveCell.Offset(x, 16).Value & """`, making it clear that the intent is to grab the cell's, well, *value*.

Comment: @PhillKnight please remember to mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Apologies, now complete